# Bash: executing a command stored in a variable

Tags: bash

I am writing a script, and one part of it is not working as I would expect.

I have broken out this part in a simple example for simplicity:

```
echo 'echo "" > tmp' | while read cmd; do  $cmd ; done
```

Here I would expect the full command, "echo "" > tmp" to be executed by $cmd.

But this happens:

```
"" > tmp
```

The command executed echoes out "" > tmp literally. Instead of echoing out "" and redirecting it to the file tmp. Obviously something is wrong when storing the command in $cmd and then later trying to execute it.

The result is the same even if I simplify it further:

```
cmd="echo "" > tmp"
$cmd
> tmp
```

I have tried to experiment with different usages of `''` and `""`, but not solved it yet.

Comment: Please read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eval` to execute the command stored in the variable:

```
echo 'echo "" > tmp' | while read cmd; do eval "$cmd" ; done
```

The value of `cmd` will be `echo "" > tmp`. Then when Bash resolves the parameter substitution as a command, the part `"" > tmp` will be the string arguments of `echo`, not be recognized as `>`(redirection). So it will just output the arguments part.

The same as: `$(echo 'echo "" > tmp')`

Comment: Warning: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet. It tends to work great when you test it, but cause occasional bizarre results when you run it on real data. And in my experience, if `eval` looks like the answer, it usually means you're asking the wrong question and really should back up and look for a different approach to the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Just for clarity: could you provide an alternative solution, then? Thanks.

Comment: @AlmirCampos It depends on the larger situation. You have to look at why you're trying to run a command stored in a variable, and whether there's a better way to solve the larger problem (usually there is). If not, are there parts of the command that might contain dangerous/misparsable shell syntax, and do you have a way to quote/escape them to avoid problems?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
do  $cmd ;
```

to

```
do  eval  "$cmd" ;
```

Comment: See my comment under zhenguoli's answer. Also, if you must use `eval`, at least double-quote the variable to avoid some *really* bizarre bugs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Point noted..Yes double quoting to prevent word splitting mainly here...