# Bash: Locate and execute a file

Tags: bash

Inside a bash shell script, I am attempting to

- Find an executable in an unknown position the current directory (guaranteed to exist)
- Run that executable, passing in a set of files as arguments.

Given that:

- The executable may be in a different sub-directory on a given system (No control over that)
- The executable will not be in `$PATH`

Currently, I can find the executable using:

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    EXECUTABLE=$(find . -name 'executable_name*' -type f)
```

*(suffix wildcard for platform-related reasons)*

Trying to then execute it fails, returning:

```sh
    No such file or directory ./path/to/executable_name
```

*Note: The executable does work if I supply the exact path returned by `find` explicitly

Trying the following two options all fail with the same error:

- `$EXECUTABLE {...}`
- `eval "$EXECUTABLE {...}"` [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745441/bash-executing-command-stored-in-variable)

As far as I understand using `-exec {}` with `find`  will pass the `find` results as args to the executable, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Setting execution permissions beforehand on the target file also yields the same results

Comment: What about `find . -name 'executable*' -type f -exec '{}' arg1 arg2 ... ';'`? The `{}` refers to the path of the executable found.

Comment: `executable=$(find find . -name 'executable_name*' -type f); command "$executable" arg1 arg2 ....` or you might want to put an `echo` in front.

Comment: Thanks @tectux, this does let me work around this issue by not having to bind the output of `find` to a variable (Needs multiple uses now)
Leaving this open in case someone can help with the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
find . -name 'executable_name*' -type f | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the executable was found in a path that contains spaces. In that case you have to quote your variable.

For example:

```
$ cat with\ spaces/test.sh 
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo test
$ foo=$(find with\ spaces/ -type f -name '*.sh')
$ echo $foo
with spaces/test.sh
$ $foo
bash: with: command not found...
$ "$foo"
test
```

Another possibility is that in your script you `cd` to another directory somewhere between executing `find` (and storing its output in the variable) and calling the executable.

Comment: I can confirm that even with no spaces in the path the problem persists. Thanks!